# javafx: How to bind disable button with dynamic created checkboxes?

Tags: javafx

I want to bind the `disable` of a button with dynamically created checkboxes. The `Button` should be enabled if a checkbox is selected.

This is my code

```
public class DietTabPageController {
    @FXML
    private FlowPane parent;
    @FXML
    private Button okButton;

    private ObservableList<CheckBox> checkBoxes=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        ObservableList<Diet> diets = DietDAO.getDiets();
        diets.forEach(diet -> checkBoxes.add(new CheckBox(diet.getName())));
        //checkboxes added in parent Flowpane
        parent.getChildren().addAll(checkBoxes);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: You want to set the `disable` property of the `okButton` to `false` iff there is at least one `CheckBox` that is selected?

Comment: Yes,  the disable button is true in fxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaFX's really nice `Bindings`-class!
Try this:

```
okButton.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        ()->!checkBoxes.stream().anyMatch(CheckBox::isSelected), 
        checkBoxes.stream().map(x->x.selectedProperty()).toArray(Observable[]::new)
    )
);
```

This creates a new Binding, which will listen on every checkbox and then call the given function to calculate the value of your property.
Additional reading here: [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html)

Regarding your comment:
I don't know how much you can edit your Diet class, but if you can, there is a very simple way to display your checkboxes and add the button-binding. Take a look at the following sample:

```
ListView<Diet> dietsView = new ListView<>(diets);
dietsView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(diet -> 
diet.selectedProperty()));

btn.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> !diets.stream().anyMatch(diet->diet.isSelected()),
        diets.stream().map(x->x.selectedProperty())
        .toArray(Observable[]::new)
    )
);
```

add this to Diet class:

```
private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
    return this.selected;
}

public final boolean isSelected() {
    return this.selectedProperty().get();
}

public final void setSelected(final boolean on) {
    this.selectedProperty().set(on);
}
```

Comment: I code a method `SpeciesDietDAO.getDietsBySpecies(Species species)`. This method retrieves `ObservableList<Diet>` depending **species**. Is posibble to set selected checkboxes from `SpeciesDietDAO.getDietsBySpecies(Speciesspecies)` without destroying binding idea? I code 2 nested for and i guess no better idea. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You need to add listeners to all the `selected` properties of the `CheckBox`es. Every time one of the property changes, modify the `Button`'s `disable` property, if necessary. BTW: Making `checkBoxes` observable doesn't seem necessary:

```
private List<CheckBox> checkBoxes;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    ObservableList<Diet> diets = DietDAO.getDiets();
    checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>(diets.size());

    ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            // activate button since at least one CheckBox is selected
            okButton.setDisable(false);
        } else {
            // disable button, if the last CheckBox was unselected
            for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                if (cb.isSelected()) {
                    return; // don't do anything, if there still is a selected CheckBox
                }
            }
            okButton.setDisable(true);
        }
    };

    for (Diet diet : diets) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(diet.getName());
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
        checkBoxes.add(cb);
    }

    //checkboxes added in parent Flowpane
    parent.getChildren().addAll(checkBoxes);
}
```

Comment: isn't this destroying the whole idea of having fx-properties?

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic Huh???? I don't know what you mean. You need to react to (un)selection of `CheckBox`es to dynamically set the `disableProperty`. Not everything needs to be done via bindings. The only thing where this could go wrong would be for the initial value, but since the button is disabled and the `CheckBox`es are unselected the UI is in a consistent state. In this case using a binding would just make the code less readable.

Comment: yes, but everything in JavaFX is a property, and every property can have bindings, so why code something, that is builtin?

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic Why create 3+ more objects just for the sake of using bindings? BTW: If I'd go with the less readable, less efficient code you posted below, (using `okButton.setDisable(checkBoxes.stream().noneMatch(CheckBox::isSelected))`) the code would also be 1 line shorter than yours, if you consider this a criterion for quality...

Comment: yes, but your code executes just 1 time? what if the user deselects a checkbox again? Bindings are here to glue together what is meant to be together. And i think the Binding-version is much more readable. You know on the first look, that this code will modify the disable-state in any way. I can't say that about your version...

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic `cb.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);` It's executed once for every (un)selection of a `ComboBox`.